# 3 divs rearrange div stack on mobile

Tags: css

[image]

Desktop 
a - 30%
b - 30%
c - 70%

all 100% on mobile

Hi trying to achieve the following layout , taught about inclosing a and b in a container , but that wont work on mobile , i'm sure one of you css junkies , has the answer.
I am familiar with media queries.

this is what i got so far which is not right

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>

#a{
    width : 30%;
    background-color : black;
}
#b{
    width : 30%;
    background-color : orange;  
}
#c{
    width : 70%;
    background-color : green;
    float : right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YcJLL/

Comment: Can you just show the css code?

Comment: Hi @Sudharsan if i float left , how will b go under a ,dont think that will work

Comment: OK show the code how could i know your code i am not genius

Comment: @Sudharsan my good man  , I am no genius thats why i need your good help.  i have updated question.

Comment: dom rendered as from your order. if you want rearrage against default go for position:absolute

Comment: i dont have mobile to test but you can try here's my update [http://jsfiddle.net/YcJLL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/YcJLL/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Ja7Bt/3/

Add `float: right` to `#c` and `float: left` to `#a` for desktop.

and for mobile give `width: auto, float: none` to `#a, #b, #c`

HTML

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}
#a{
    width : 30%;
    background-color : black;
    float: left
}
#b{
    width : 30%;
    background-color : orange;  
}
#c{
    width : 70%;
    background-color : green;
    float : right;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {

#a, #b, #c {
    float: none;
    width: auto
}
}
```

Comment: your answer works with a mofication , change it to 
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<div id="b">b</div>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<div id="b">b</div>

#a{
    float: left;
    width : 30%;
    background-color : black;
}
#b{
    float: left;
    width : 30%;
    background-color : orange;  
}
#c{
    width : 70%;
    background-color : green;
    float : right;
}
#a, #b, #c {
    color: white;
 }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #a, #b, #c {
    float: none;
    width: auto
  }
}
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/Ja7Bt/1/

Answer (score 0):

See the updated fiddle. Hope that's what you are trying to do.

```
<div class="left">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .left {
        width:30%;
        float:left
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YcJLL/3/